# Using Command line argument that contains quotes and spaces, e.g. an XML string

Tags: cmd

I am writing a command line executable that performs XML operations. I want the ability to pass in an XML string directly as a parameter in the command line, but I am having difficulty dealing with the double quotes (") used in the XML attributes. I tried using the escape character (^"), but that does not seem to work. How do I format the parameter to pass in correctly?

Here is an example of what isn't working so far:

```
"<?xml version=^"1.0^" encoding=^"UTF-8^"?><sbml xmlns=^"http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2/version4^" level=^"2^" version=^"4^"><model metaid=^"_case00001^" id=^"case00001^" name=^"case00001^"></model></sbml>"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sbml xmlns="http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2/version4" level="2" version="4"><model metaid="_case00001" id="case00001" name="case00001"></model></sbml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally backslash is used to escape dbl quotes for strings, not the same as parsing xml so try using \", or, replace them with single quotes where you can.

Answer (score 0):

Try to excape not the qoutes but '<' and '>':
This works on my tests in cmd's command line:

```
  somecommand.exe "^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?^>^<sbml xmlns="http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2/version4" level="2" version="4"^>^<model metaid="_case00001" id="case00001" name="case00001"^>^</model^>^</sbml^>"
```